# JMeter while loop (stop loop using its own index)

Tags: loops, jmeter

I'm using JMeter 5.0 and i'm trying to loop over a database resultset.

For the sake of simplicity here we'll just use "3" instead of vars.getObject("resultSet").size() which is my resultset's size)

I'm trying to use the WHILE component's own index to make it stop

(Please do not show me how to use the counter component since I could make it work myself given all the help i've found regarding JMeter's WHILE uses a counter , but it is counter-intuitive to me (no pun intended), just like incrementing "i" in any other language :

```
` 
for(int i = 0;i < 10;)
    {
   // do stuff
    i++;
    }
`
```

I the syntaxes i found and tried  (my while component is named LOOP):

1. `${__jm__LOOP__idx}  < 3` : Returns no error but does not stop
2. `${__javaScript("${__jm__LOOP__idx}" < 3 )}` : Returns no error but does not loop either.
3. `${__javaScript(${__jm__LOOP__idx} < 3)}` : 
   Works and stops looping after 3 but returns this error :

   `javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:1 Expected ; but found {
   ${__jm__LOOP__idx} < 3
    ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 1
       at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470) ~[nashorn.jar:?]`

Thank you in advance for any help you may provide, and for your time.

Comment: I found that using a simple loop controller instread of a while loop with :
    `${__javaScript(vars.getObject("resultSet").size())}` as number of loops is way simple

Comment: After experimenting a little more, i found out that the index is not defined when the test is first done, but only in the first loop. When I add a BeanShell sample with : 
    `vars.put("__jm__LOOP__idx","0");`  before the loop i dont get the error anymore..

Comment: Your analysis is correct, see my answer for the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) is named **LOOP**, use this as condition , it uses [__jexl3](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) function:

> ${__jexl3(vars.get("__jm__LOOP__idx") == null || vars.get("__jm__LOOP__idx") < 3,)}

Comment: Hello UBIK LOAD PACK, thank you for your answer, I get this error :
` 018-10-02 14:54:20,072 ERROR o.a.j.f.Jexl3Function: An error occurred while evaluating the expression "vars.get("__jm__LOOP__idx") == null || ${__jm__LOOP__idx} < 3"

org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlException$Ambiguous: 3@1:61 ambiguous statement error near '... {__jm__LOOP__idx} < 3 ...'
 at org.apache.commons.jexl3.parser.JexlParser.throwParsingException(JexlParser.java:270) ~[commons-jexl3-3.1.jar:3.1]
`

Comment: 5.0 r1840935 to be exact

Comment: Thank you it works, can you please explain what the extra "," does ? It seems to work when I remove it..

Comment: Thank, I tried earlier but I didn't have enough rep ^^